# Get field value from field name in Meteor template

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have two variables in my template `rows` and `fields` holding the documents and the field names in the collection, respectively.

I print it with

```
{{#each rows}}
  <tr>
    {{#each fields}}
      <td>{{name}}</td>
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

but right now it just prints the field names instead of the actual values in the documents.

I want to obtain something similar to

```
{{#each rows}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{age}}</td>
    <td>{{height}}</td>
    ...
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I assume you're saying you want to display name propery of `rows` record not in `fields`, am I right>

Comment: Yes :-) I guess I will have to create a helper to be used something like `{{getFieldValue name}}` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

try

```
{{#each rows}}
  <tr>
    {{#each fields}}
      <td>{{../name}}</td>
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: But the `name` comes from `fields`. `fields` is an array with objects `[{name: 'age'}, {name: 'height'}, ...]`, so I need to tell that I want the field in `rows` having the field names from `fields`

Comment: here name comes from rows not fields